# Can I use gradle to build a native ruby gem (not Jruby)

Tags: ruby, gradle, continuous-integration

I found a lot of examples to use gradle Jruby to build gems.
I am wondering if gradle has this support to build native ruby gems and help deploy to the assigned repo (artifactory for example)

Or please let me know what is the best to use for building Gems and deploying Gems in the CI

Comment: `bundler` for everything

Comment: Could you please be more specific. I know bundler can do a lot. But could you give me flow here. Like I have a gem that I want to develop. How to make sure the CI process it automatic and right.